# how to pass values to a html file in android

Tags: android, html-parsing

I have a HTML formatted file saved in SD card. I want to retrieve it , pass values to it and save it again from an android activity. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: what is "passing value to a HTML formatted file"?

Answer (score 0):

Use

[Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

> Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any  tags in the HTML will display as a generic replacement image which your program can then go through and replace with real images.
>   This uses TagSoup to handle real HTML, including all of the brokenness found in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by passing value to HTML formatted file either, but if you want to make operations on a file, you can do it [this way](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I have an excel spread sheet saved in html format, which I want to update with values entered by the user in the screen.